# How to convert string value in array and split and make two values in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here in my UI there is one field full name , from that I have to break firstname and lastname .
Like someone has entered "Abhi gaurav Abhi". So I have to make it array and split with space and make first 2 index as first and last index lastname . But I am facing problem , how can I make it array and split . I have wrote something what I understand , but not working please help

```
     this.state = {
          fullName: '',
          }
          
         onChangeTextForm = async (text, identifier) => {
        if (identifier === 'full name') {
          this.setState({
            fullName: text
          })
        }
        
    goToConfigureProduct = async () => {
// here in below code I have to break full name as I have written above and ,there is function below
"this.props.registrationRequest" I have to pass.

        console.log("output ",this.state.fullName);
         "Abhi Abhi Abhi"
        
        let firstname = 'Abhi';
        let lastname = 'Gaurav';
         if (fullName.length > 2) {
           firstname = fullname[0] + ' ' + fullname[1];
    
          for (var i = 2; i <= fullName.length - 1; i++) {
            lastname = lastname + fullName[i] + ' ';
          }
        } else if (fullName.length === 2) {
          firstname = fullName[0];
          lastname = fullName[1];
        } else if (length === 1) {
          firstname = fullName[0];
          lastname = fullName[0];
         }
         
          this.props.registrationRequest( firstname,lastname);
    
         }
         
         <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                          <Input
                            value={this.state.fullName}
                            placeholder="Full Name"
                            keyboardType='default'
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeTextForm(text, 'full name')}
                          />
                        </Item>
                        
                        <CustomButton labelFontSize={hp('2.5%')} disabled={isLoading} label={'Register'} that={this} fontWeight='bold'
                          onPress={() => this.goToConfigureProduct()}
                          width={deviceWidth - 40} />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way I handle that

```
    const fullName = "Abhi gaurav Abhi"
    const listName = fullName.split(' ') // ["Abhi", "gaurav", "Abhi"]
    const lastName: listName.shift() // "Abhi"
    const firstName: listName.join(' ') // "gaurav Abhi"
```

Comment: Please note of this statement: *I have to make it array and split with space and make first 2 index as first and last index lastname*

Comment: Tahnks , but  suppoere there is 3 value in "Abhi gaurav Trivedi" in this condition firtsname should be Abhi gaurav and last Trivedi..

Comment: if there is two value Abhi Gaurav then fistname Abhi and last gaurav

Comment: if full name is "name1, name2, name3" what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple approach:

#### Idea

- Accept string and split it using space to get word array.
- Remove last element from this list and set it as `lastName`
- Join the remaining items in this array using space and use it as `firstName`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#txtDummy');
input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  const text = this.value.trim();
  // In you code, it should be 
  // this.state.fullName.split(/\s+/)
  const parts = text.split(/\s+/);
  const lastName = parts.pop();
  const firstName = parts.join(' ');
  
  console.log(`First Name: ${ firstName }. Last Name: ${ lastName }`)
})
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtDummy' />
```

---

If in case you wish to keep only first value as firstName and rest as lastName, you can try like:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#txtDummy');
input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  const [ firstName, ...rest ] = input.value.trim().split(/\s+/);
  const lastName = rest.join(' ');
  
  console.log(`First Name: ${ firstName }. Last Name: ${ lastName }`)
})
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtDummy' />
```

**Note:** just to handle case when you can have multiple spaces between words, I'm using a regex: `/\s+/` instead of space

Comment: Thanks .. but in my code getting error querySelector is not defined and 
TypeError: input.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: but here your output is coming ,exactly I want that

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav You co not have to use querySelector. You have value in state. Just use that instead of `input.value`

Comment: sorry output is different .. in my codition only last value should be last name ..rest all should be in first name .. "Abhi Gaurav Trivedi" then  Trivedi should in last rest in first

Comment: I was taking from state but addEventListener is not a function error

Comment: You do not need to have an addEventListener. That was just for simulation. Also, please use first snippet. Not the second one. Please refer to explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to split the string. Use `lastIndexOf` to find the last space in the string, and split it up in substrings.

**Note**: if viable, splitting up the input fields (first name(s), last name) will be more reliable.

```js
const firstLast = name => {
  const lastIdx = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
  return `first: ${name.substr(0, lastIdx)}, last: ${name.substr(lastIdx + 1)}`;
};

console.log(firstLast("Abhi gaurav Abhi"));
console.log(firstLast("John Michael William Johnson"));
```

Comment: Thanks .. but fullName is one string value , I have to make it into the array , that is the issue

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav Do you want both values as array of strings?

Comment: full name is one input filed , from there I have to get first name and last name ..accroding to question,  but for that I need to convert fullname in array and then in two string value